# sbt project is very slow to resolve dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt

My sbt project takes more than 15 minutes when I do

```
sbt clean compile
```

I am on a beefy machine on AWS. I am fairly certain its not a resource issue on cpu or internet bandwidth. Also, I have run this command a few times and hence the ivy cache is populated.

Here is all my build related files

/build.sbt

```
name := "ProjectX"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

libraryDependencies += ("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.4.1")
  .exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12")
  .exclude("log4j", "log4j")
  .exclude("commons-logging", "commons-logging")
  .%("provided")

libraryDependencies += ("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kinesis-asl" % "1.4.1")
  .exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12")
  .exclude("log4j", "log4j")
  .exclude("commons-logging", "commons-logging")

libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "2.8.1"

//test
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test"

//logging
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  //facade
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.12",
  "org.clapper" %% "grizzled-slf4j" % "1.0.2",
  //jcl (used by aws sdks)
  "org.slf4j" % "jcl-over-slf4j" % "1.7.12",
  //log4j1 (spark)
  "org.slf4j" % "log4j-over-slf4j" % "1.7.12",
  //log4j2
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.3",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.3",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-slf4j-impl" % "2.3"
  //alternative to log4j2
  //"org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.7.5"
)
```

/project/build.properties

```
sbt.version = 0.13.8
```

/project/plugins.sbt

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

addSbtPlugin("org.scalastyle" %% "scalastyle-sbt-plugin" % "0.7.0")

resolvers += "sonatype-releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
```

/project/assembly.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.13.0")
```

Comment: Have you run `sbt -v' to get some verbose sbt output? It might give your a hint which modules take long to resolve or which repositories. Note: a couple of repositories at *artifactoryonline.com* got migrated to *bintray.com* and were shut down recently.

Comment: so, it's slow even when artifacts are already in ivy cache?

Comment: We have the same problem.  Using scala 2.11.7 & sbt 13.9.   DNS resolution is quick <3ms.  But the actually resolve of each dependency takes several seconds... and in a big project that can be half an hour.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to a current sbt (1.9 as of writing this) should improve this. In the 1.x series, dependency resolution began to use a new backend which is dramatically faster.

Answer (score 0):

On the log do you see entries like:

```
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.10;1.4.1!spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.10.jar (239ms)
```

That's a sign that you're downloading these artifacts. In other words, the AMI you're launching doesn't have the Ivy cache populated.

Using sbt 0.13.12 on my laptop with SSD, I get about 5s for `clean` and then `update`.

```
so-31956971> update
[info] Updating {file:/xxx/so-31956971/}app...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[success] Total time: 5 s, completed Aug 25, 2016 4:00:00 AM
```